# How to fetch nth recent value?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table named "friendbook_post" with the following fields: `text`, `id`, `type`, `author`, `date_time`. 
There are many entries in the table .

Now I want to fetch 2nd post(according to time) of every author (if exist) along with author id(author) and date.

I tried many queries but nothing helped me .

Comment: What is your RDBMS: MySQL or Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an analytic function (in this case, `ROW_NUMBER()`) along with a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT text, id, type, author, date_time, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY author ORDER BY date_time DESC ) AS the_post_num
      FROM friendbook_post
) WHERE the_post_num = 2
```

This will give the 2nd newest post (2nd most recent). If you want to get the 2nd oldest post then `ORDER BY date_time ASC`. And `2` can be replaced with any `n`. Note that if an author doesn't have a 2nd post then the above query won't return anything for that author.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks I got the ans after a little modification in your query. Actually partition should be according to 'author' because id is the primary key and there will be only one row associated  with one id.so ans will be always null.

Comment: My apologies, I misread your initial post. I read author id(author) as referring to the column named "id" rather than that named "author"

Comment: I've modified my answer; would you please accept it? Thanks.